# Get string timezone from numeric timezone value PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, timezone

Is there a way to find Timezone string from timestamp Integer value?

```
My Integer value : +5.5
```

What I want to get

```
Asia/Colombo
```

I'm working on WordPress, Is there an easy way to get that on WP?

Comment: So, `+5.5` means `+5:30` right?

Comment: you probably not able to get the exact timezone using the offset (+5.5) because this offset belongs to more than one timezones **Asia/Colombo** , **Asia/Kolkata**, however you can check [following code](http://codepad.org/6rlk8gQh)

Comment: Yeah, offset belongs to many time zones. Thanks for the example code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `DateTimeZone::listIdentifiers()`

```
$time_zones =  DateTimeZone::listIdentifiers();

foreach ($time_zones as $time_zone) {
    $date = new DateTime('now', new DateTimeZone($time_zone));
    $offset_in_hours = $date->getOffset() / 60 / 60;
    echo "{$time_zone}: ($offset_in_hours)";
}
```

This will output something like:

```
Asia/Choibalsan: (9)
Asia/Colombo: (5.5)
Asia/Damascus: (3)
Asia/Dhaka: (6)
Asia/Dili: (9)
Asia/Dubai: (4)
```

Then you can wrap this code inside a plugin/shortcode and use the output to reverse search your time zone.

Answer (score -2):

No, because a time zone offset and a time zone are two very different things.

See "time zone != offset" in [the timezone tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info).